# Research into Advantages of Having a Standard Coding Style

Tags: styles, conventions

There are a couple of questions on Stackoverflow on whether there is any research or studies into what is the best coding convention/style.  That's not what this question is about.  This question is about whether there are any studies that research whether there are any advantages, productivity gains or other positive side effects to having an organization-wide coding convention and style.

I have my own opinions on this, which is basically that there is huge benefits to having such standards in place. Honestly, I couldn't care less what style I am required to use as long as it is consistent in all the code I might have to work with.

I just want to know if there are any studies that back my opinions or contradict them.

Comment: "huge benefits"?  Or "benefits"?  What do you mean by huge?  Is standard style more valuable than automated unit testing?  More valuable than a good language?  More valuable than simple, effective design?

Comment: @S.Lott - just a bit of hyperbole. I myself prefer understatement, and people sometimes misunderstand that, too.

Comment: I suspect you could care less.  What if the coding style for C included such things as "no unnecessary whitespace (including newlines) allowed"? or "multi-word comments describing the usage of a variable must appear intermixed with each letter of the declaration: eg int t/*height*/a/*of*/l/*character*/l;"  Those are extreme examples, but I suspect "couldn't care less" is an exaggeration. :)

Comment: @S.Lott It's not a comparison of different parts or technologies of the software development process.  I stick to the fact that I think it has HUGE benefits from a perspective of maintenance, inter-team flexibility and being able to comprehend others code without having to take time to adapt your built-in pattern recognition to an unfamiliar coding style.

Comment: @William Pursell Maybe "Couldn't Care Less" is a bit strong.  Lets say within reason.  You're speaking of edge cases that would never fly when a company as a whole sets out to design a standard convention. With that said, I think I could more easily adapt to one bad convention that is strictly enforced compared to hundreds of individual conventions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There have been several studies showing that a strict adherence to a consistent visual style helps experienced programmers keep more of the local problem in memory without having to memorize the individual elements of the problem.

### Consistent Coding Style Aids Chunking

It has to do with how the human memory works. It is called *chunking*. For example, it is a well-studied phenomenon that **chess masters are much better at memorizing** chess positions than people who are not familiar with the game. But that is only if the pieces occur in "natural positions" that can occur in a normal game. If you place the chess pieces in random positions, chess masters are ***no better off* than non-chess players** at memorizing board positions.

The same concept applies to programmers. When coding styles are consistent, the coding constructs appear "natural" to the programmer and larger portions of the code are easier to assimilate. Our short term memory has a capacity of about "seven plus-or-minus two" chunks so, the larger those familiar chunks are, the more raw data our mind can actively hold in memory ([George Miller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Armitage_Miller)).

When faced with randomly-formatted code, programmers have to expend addition mental energy to **manually parse out the individual pieces** of the problem they are working on. That takes away from the ability to hold larger pieces of the problem in memory to work on it. It also means that it takes longer to reach a point where the programmer is productively solving the problem at hand.

### Flow Time

Have you ever found that a problem seems so clear while you continue to work on it but then you seem to "lose the information" when you come back to the problem later; i.e. break your flow time? Flow time is well-documented in [Peopleware](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321934113) (a must read for all programmers). Flow time is when programmers get a large majority of work done and is only achieved when you are working on a problem for an extended, uninterupted period of time. That is because it takes a certain period of time for a programmer to assimilate enough of the problem into cognitive memory to effectively work on the problem. Well-formatted code helps our visual image processing which means programmers reach flow time much faster.

I have authored coding standards at several software companies. It is unfortunate how many programmers feel that coding standards are just a means of asserting unneeded control over how they do things; a form of creative censorship. Truth be told, it rarely matters what the actual standards are. The value is in getting everyone on a team to be consistent, even if it means making an often-arbitrary decision between doing it *my* way or doing it *your* way.

Here are a few reference I mentioned above:

- [Peopleware: Productive Projects and Teams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321934113) **<-- A Must Read**
- [Empirical Studies of Programmers - Cognitive Analysis of a Code Inspection](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=hWANlli2xrMC&oi=fnd&pg=PP11&dq=%22Empirical+Studies+of+Programming+Knowledge.%22&ots=hlD2eNkEy4&sig=vBga8qa9Xr3tXKUfvB3MxKT4bi0#v=onepage&q=%22Empirical%20Studies%20of%20Programming%20Knowledge.%22&f=false)
- [The Chess Memory](http://chess.eusa.ed.ac.uk/Chess/Trivia/chessmemory.html)
- [A computer model of chess memory](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/%7Ehsstffg/papers/ModelChessMem/Chess%20Memory.html)
- [Chunking (psychology)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_%28psychology%29)

Comment: This is a great answer, Robert. Thanks.

I'm sure we've all experienced chunking.  I know when I'm looking at properly formatted code, relative to what I consider proper of course, that I can comprehend the code as a whole.  But as soon as the code is slightly formatted differently (i.e. a curly bracket not opening where I expect it to) the ability to grasp it as a whole is gone, resulting in me having to go through each line.

Breaking the illusive flow is another great point.

Comment: Chunking tends to be more negative than positive in my experience because it makes programmers make assumptions based on certain consistencies that are false. Insisting that consistency leads to "better" code is inconclusive and has no real double-blind studies associated with it. Confirmation bias.

Answer (score 7):

> Our studies support the claim that knowledge of programming plans and rules of programming discourse can have a significant impact on program comprehension. In their book called [The] Elements of [Programming] Style, Kernighan and Plauger also identify what we would call discourse rules. Our empirical results put teeth into these rules: It is not merely a matter of aesthetics that programs should be written in a particular style. Rather there is a psychological basis for writing programs in a conventional manner: programmers have strong expectations that other programmers will follow these discourse rules. If the rules are violated, then the utility afforded by the expectations that programmers have built up over time is effectively nullified. The results from the experiments with novice and advanced student programmers and with professional programmers described in this paper provide clear support for these claims.

[Empirical Studies of Programming Knowledge. Soloway and Ehrlich.](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~redmiles/inf233-FQ07/oldpapers/SollowayEhrlich.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The place I gained the most insight on the issue:

[C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) (Sutter, Alexandrescu)

It's worth reading even if you aren't working in C++.