# do naming rules in kotlin matter

Tags: kotlin, naming, rules

An absolute pet hate are naming rules for the sake of it, when development enviroments are so good at letting users know what each item is.

As the title suggests are there any pitfalls if a developer were to name all types, objects, variables etc.. 'all in "snake_case", specifically in Kotlin.  Ignoring the auto generated names for binding etc.

Comment: You should stick to Kotlin conventions (which in turn are derrived from Java) -- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html

Comment: Naming rules aren't for the sake of it. They make code more readable and faster to skim, with or without IDE color coding.

Answer (score 2):

Coding style, such as naming, doesn't matter to the compiler.

But it matters to humans — and as a couple of wise people once said, “[programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Programming_languages#A_-_F)”  (They were probably exaggerating for effect, but I think there's still a grain of truth there.)

Consistency in naming means that you don't have to stop and think about whether to use underscores or capitals (or spaces or dashes or whatever inside backquotes); it makes classes and methods easier to find in your code as well as in libraries and frameworks; it plays better with Kotlin properties (which look for `getXxx`/`setXxx`/`isXxx` method in the bytecode); it removes a source of disagreement among developers; it's less likely to cause problems with IDEs and frameworks and source-code tools which tend to assume you're using standard naming conventions; it makes the codebase easier for new developers to get up to speed with.

But, more than all those, code which doesn't follow conventions *i*S_нa℞-τଠɘⱭ.  When things that work the same *look* the same, differences are easier to see.  The less time you spend deciphering names, that more time is left for understanding what the code is doing with them.  It's the same reason why we use consistent indentation and spacing and structure and design patterns.  With fewer surface differences, you can more easily see the underlying structures and patterns in the code, and deviations (and hence bugs) become more obvious.

Coding — by which I include debugging, maintaining, and enhancing as well as writing fresh code — is *hard*, and we humans are limited, so we should make things as easy for ourselves as possible.  Developing software is a constant battle against complexity; every little simplification helps.  You may think that using snake_case instead of camelCase is insignificant; but the mere fact you're asking about it here shows that it makes a difference!

The answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288989/what-is-the-actual-value-of-a-consistent-code-style) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325374/research-into-advantages-of-having-a-standard-coding-style) give many more (and better-argued) reasons why consistency is important.

(As it happens, I've spent many years using languages which prefer snake_case, and also with those which prefer camelCase, and I definitely find the latter easier to read in context.  But that's a much less important consideration than consistency.)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from arguing about that with other developers, and calls to all library functions looking different, the language will work perfectly and not care about that.